# JQuery Accordion Default Close

Tags: jquery

```
<p><!-- JS --><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
  });
  });
 </script><!-- CSS -->
<style type="text/css">.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
.accordion-content {display: none;}
.accordion-content.default {display: block;}
</style>
<!-- HTML --></p>
```

Where can I put code to have the default load all closed until clicked on?

Comment: I'm not sure what JSFiddle means.

Comment: where u can put the js code and test there check this link http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close accordian by default, put below line as first line in `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".accordion-content").slideUp('fast');
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
       $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: That's all there is. The rest would be HTML after that.

Comment: That closed it but now I can't open anything of the headings.

Comment: Please see updated answer, rest of the code means your script code not html. Could you please share HTML code so that I can get the elements position and suggest you the solution in better way.

Answer (score 0):

you can see what is the html difference between click and unclick. after clicked, the html would  change the style  from "display: black;" into "display: none;"。 so you should know how to code!